# SVG path versus SVG source

Tags: json, extjs, svg

I am making an Icon Generator for internal use.  I was going to store the svg path data in a database and return it in json.  Is there any benefit to saving the actual svg file and returning to source over just returning the path?

I want to just store the path so I don't have to worry about the files.

In progress demo (in extjs): http://codepen.io/jesseRules/pen/zxbjWj?editors=011

```
<codepen http://codepen.io/jesseRules/pen/zxbjWj?  </codepen>
```

Comment: I had to put some code. Stack doesn't like codepen links apparently.  But I don't need help with the code, more best practices.  My google-fu was failing me.

Comment: Isn't pulling the path definitions out of the SVG files, storing them in the DB, then regenerating the SVGs at runtime making things more complicated than it needs to be?  Plus putting unnecessary load on your DB?  Static SVG files can be served more efficiently, served by a CDN, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I secretly thought what I was doing was dumb. I think the svg file route will be better.